# Reassigning elements (pointers in particular) in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to take a struct, "trash" it, and reassign the values of its elements.  I wrote the following example code, and it seems to work.  But I am wondering if anyone sees anything wrong with it.  I am mainly worried about the "name" and "ip" pointers.  They came out looking right, but did I just get lucky?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct stuff_s{

   int n;
   char *name;
   int dsize;
   int *ip;

} stuff;


void output_stuff(stuff *s){

   int n;

   printf("%d\n", s->n);
   printf("%s\n", s->name);
   printf("%d\n", s->dsize);

   for (n=0; n<s->dsize; n++) {
      printf("%d ",s->ip[n]);
   }

   printf("\n");

}


void reassign(stuff *s) {

   stuff snew;
   int n;

   snew.n = 2;
   snew.name = calloc(32, sizeof(char));
   strcpy(snew.name, "Snoopy");
   snew.dsize = 12;
   snew.ip = calloc(snew.dsize, sizeof(int));
   for (n=0; n<snew.dsize; n++) { snew.ip[n] = n; }

   free(s->name);
   free(s->ip);

   memcpy(s, &snew, sizeof(stuff));

}


int main() {

   stuff d;
   int n;

   d.n = 1;
   d.dsize = 10;
   d.ip = calloc(d.dsize, sizeof(int));
   for (n=0; n<d.dsize; n++) {
      d.ip[n] = n;
   } 
   d.name = calloc(32, sizeof(char));
   strcpy(d.name,"Charlie Brown");

   output_stuff(&d);
   printf("\n");

   reassign(&d);

   output_stuff(&d);

   free(d.ip);
   free(d.name);

}
```

Comment: looks ok to me.

Comment: There is no need for snew, just do the frees first and then assign to the passed s. s->name = calloc...

Comment: `printf("\n");` -> `putchar ('\n');` There is no need to call the variadic `printf` to output a single character.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir   You are right about this little test code.  For reasons I didn't want to get into, in my real code `memcpy` would be a better option if it can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **did I just get lucky?**

Well, you got lucky, but not for the reasons you may be thinking...

Your handling of the stuct allocation and reassignment was correct, but incomplete. You should ***validate*** all memory allocations to insure you do not invoke *Undefined Behavior* by attempting to access memory that does not belong to you in the event of an allocation failure.

For example, when you allocate `d.ip` -- **check the return** to insure `calloc` succeeded, e.g.

```
    if (!(d.ip = calloc (d.dsize, sizeof *d.ip))) {
        perror ("calloc d.ip failed");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

You should do that for every allocation.

Type `void` for `reassign` is insufficient. It provides no meaningful way to determine whether the allocations in the function succeeded or not. Any time you are allocating memory, opening a file, taking input, etc.. make sure you declare your function with a type that can provide a meaningful return to indicate *success* or *failure*. A pointer returning a valid address or `NULL` works, as does an integer type returning a value that can indicate success/failure.

Don't use magic numbers in your code. If you need a constant for instance for the size of the `name` member, then `#define` one or use an `enum`. For example if you want the size of `name` to be `32` bytes, then define a namesize constant, e.g.

```
#define NMSZ 32
```

Your `reassign` function continues with *magic numbers* and *magic strings* in making assignments to `.n`, `.dsize`, and `.dname`. (granted, I understand that is was likely for a quick test). Make `reassign` useful by passing the values of `n`, `name` and `dsize` as function parameters.

You don't need to `memcpy (s, &snew, sizeof (stuff));`. All you need to do is assign `*s = snew;`. Now you may be a bit lucky here since you limited the pointer members of your struct to single pointers. Since the value contained is the address of the start of each memory block, an assignment is all that is required. However, if you use a *pointer to pointer to type* as a member (e.g. a double-pointer) an assignment (or a `memcpy`) is no longer sufficient, and a deep copy will be required.

**note:** unless you need `name` to be modifiable (e.g. you need to change individual characters), then a *string literal* can be used and eliminate the need to dynamically allocate altogether.

It may also be wise to change your choice of `int n;` to `int i;` as the counter to eliminate confusion between `n` and `s.n`, etc..

Putting those pieces together, you could make `reassign` a bit more robust as follows:

```
stuff *reassign (stuff *s, int n, const char *name, int dsize) {

    stuff snew;
    int i;

    snew.n = n; /* validate all memory allocations */
    if (!(snew.name = calloc (NMSZ, sizeof *snew.name))) {
        perror ("calloc snew.name");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (snew.name, name);

    snew.dsize = dsize; /* ditto */
    if (!(snew.ip = calloc (snew.dsize, sizeof *snew.ip))) {
        perror ("calloc snew.ip");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < snew.dsize; i++)
        snew.ip[i] = i + 5;

    free (s->name);
    free (s->ip);

    *s = snew;  /* you can simply assign snew */

    return s;
}
```

While you are free to assign each member of your struct after declaration, beginning with C99, use of named-initializers make a simple and readable way to initialize non-dynamic members at the time of declaration, e.g.

```
    stuff d = { .n = 1, .dsize = 10 };
```

Finally, as noted in the comments, there is no need to call `printf ("\n");` to output a single character. That is what `putchar ('\n');` is for. Granted, a decent compiler will make the optimization for you, but that isn't an excuse for not using the correct tool for the job to begin with.

Putting all the pieces together, you could make your code a bit more robust and protect against *Undefined Behavior* by adding validations and making use of the meaningful return from `reassign` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NMSZ 32

typedef struct stuff_s {
    int n,
        dsize,
        *ip;
    char *name;
} stuff;


void output_stuff (stuff *s){

    int n;

    printf ("%d\n%s\n%d\n", s->n, s->name, s->dsize);

    for (n = 0; n < s->dsize; n++)
        printf ("%d ",s->ip[n]);

    putchar ('\n');
}


stuff *reassign (stuff *s, int n, const char *name, int dsize) {

    stuff snew;
    int i;

    snew.n = n; /* validate all memory allocations */
    if (!(snew.name = calloc (NMSZ, sizeof *snew.name))) {
        perror ("calloc snew.name");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (snew.name, name);

    snew.dsize = dsize; /* ditto */
    if (!(snew.ip = calloc (snew.dsize, sizeof *snew.ip))) {
        perror ("calloc snew.ip");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < snew.dsize; i++)
        snew.ip[i] = i + 5;

    free (s->name);
    free (s->ip);

    *s = snew;  /* you can simply assign snew */

    return s;
}

int main() {

    stuff d = { .n = 1, .dsize = 10 };
    int i;

    if (!(d.ip = calloc (d.dsize, sizeof *d.ip))) {
        perror ("calloc d.ip failed");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < d.dsize; i++)
        d.ip[i] = i;

    if (!(d.name = calloc (NMSZ, sizeof *d.name))) {
        perror ("calloc d.name failed");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy (d.name, "Charlie Brown");

    output_stuff (&d);
    putchar ('\n');

    if (reassign (&d, 2, "Linus", 12)) {

        output_stuff (&d);

        free (d.ip);
        free (d.name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/structcpy
1
Charlie Brown
10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

2
Linus
12
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Look thins over an let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: @david-c-rankin  Wow!  That was alot of work!  Thanks.  As you mentioned, I left out several of the points you mention (validation, magic numbers, etc.) since this was just supposed to be a test code.  I still see some things I hadn't thought about, though, so thanks.  Your comment about double pointers is spot on.  I should have mentioned that.  If I can bother you further, why would a deep copy be needed?  Say ip is actually **int.  Then I populate the new ip[0], ip[1], etc.  Then I replace ip with the new ip.  It seems to me that the new data is available and correctly pointed to.

Comment: When using a double-pointer (a pointer to pointer), regardless whether you `memcpy` or assign the struct to copy one to the other, the copy will only see the first level. Neither `memcpy` or assignment has any way of knowing what memory address was assigned to the 2nd level. And since it is not part of the struct, `memcpy` or assigning the struct has no way to get the address. That is when you must do a *deep copy* (meaning, you have to copy each member that contain pointers to additional blocks of memory). Now you can assign, then deep copy the rest `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's what [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) says:

```
1
--2097-- REDIR: 0x4ebf9c0 (strlen) redirected to 0x4c2e0e0 (strlen)
Charlie Brown
10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

--2097-- REDIR: 0x4eb9d10 (free) redirected to 0x4c2bd80 (free)
--2097-- REDIR: 0x4ec8630 (memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x4a25720 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--2097-- REDIR: 0x4ed1620 (__memcpy_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c2f6b0 (memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14)
2
Snoopy
12
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
==2097==
==2097== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2097==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2097==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 152 bytes allocated
==2097==
==2097== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2097==
==2097== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==2097== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So there are no memory errors.

Some stylistic points

1. You don't need to use `sizeof(char)` - it's defined to be 1
2. `dsize` should be unsigned, and should really be a `size_t`, which is bigger than an `int`
3. As SoronellHaetir points out, you don't need to use another struct - you can modify the passed-in one